# How can I connect to server socket running inside a docker container from another machine?

Tags: java, docker

In one system, I am having a docker container, In that a Server Socket was ready to accept the client socket. So, How can I connect to the server socket from another system?

The container IP and port was: 171.18.1.4:9090

Server socket port was: 3333

How can I connect the client socket to the server socket?

Note: I am using java for this program

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by sending http requests for example via curl:

```
curl -X GET http://your.ip.address.sth/9090
```

Bear in mind that here the address is the ip address of your machine and not of the docker Container. Docker operates in private network and publishes a port to your computers network. So just google „what is my ip“ and google will tell u ur machines public ip.

I am assuming 9090 is the port your docker container has published

Comment: How can I connect to the server socket that is running inside a container?
For example: In my container, I am running a server socket program in port 1234. So how  can I connect to server socket from another machine?

Comment: you need to read a bit how docker works, I explained it already but in simple words your docker container is inside of a private network that is why you "publish" a port which basically binds that port to your computers outer network. So step 1 when you start your container make sure to use `-p 1234:1234` which will bind its 1234 port to your machines 1234 port. After that just send a request (which will create a connection) from somewhere else to your computers ipaddress:port